# Tricky shifting baseline in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to perform calculations, grouping by two different column as well as creating a baseline where the values are calculated off of.

**Data**

```
id  Date    ppm pos_diff    finalppm    finalpos    t   t_cnt   ex  ex_cnt
aa  Q122    40  3           160         7           50      2   0   0
aa  Q222    10  1           150         6           0       0   0   0
bb  Q122   -10 -2           510         7           0       0   0   0
bb  Q222    10  2           500         5           0       0   50  3
bb  Q322    50  8           450        -3           0       0   0   0
bb  Q422    50  3           400        -6           20      2   0   0
```

**Desired**

```
id  Date    ppm pos_diff    finalppm    finalpos    t   t_cnt   ex  ex_cnt  final   final_cnt
aa  Q122    40  3           160         7           50  2       0   0       110     5
aa  Q222    10  1           150         6           0   0       0   0       100     4
bb  Q122   -10 -2           510         7           0   0       0   0       510     7
bb  Q222    10  2           500         5           0   0       50  3       550     8
bb  Q322    50  8           450        -3           0   0       0   0       500     0
bb  Q422    50  3           400        -6           20  2       0   0       430    -5
```

*Logic*

Making sure we are grouping by the 'id' and 'date' column, we first need to perform this calculation for the first row of each new id. This is our initial baseline.

'final'    = 'finalppm' -  't' + 'ex'
'finalcnt' = 'finalpos' -  't_cnt'  +  'ex_cnt'

Once we have calculated the value for the FIRST ‘final’ value, we then use this value (example 110) and subtract the ‘ppm’ value from it, as well as the ‘t’ column value. Lastly we add the ‘ex’ value.

'final'- 'ppm' - 't' + 'ex' , which gives us the next 'final' value
(same logic for 'final_cnt')

**Doing**

Trying to adjust this to achieve the desired output, but I am missing a few inputs. I am still researching. Any suggestion is helpful.

A SO member suggested something similar:

```
df['final'].add(df.groupby('id')['ex'].cumsum())
                 .sub(df.groupby('id')['t'].cumsum())
```

Comment: Firsty, Since you are grouping by two columns I assume you want some aggregation function, yet I don’t see one mentioned, would you like the sum/mean/first etc? Secondly, the calculation you showed doesn’t match the output (for example aa Q222 doesn’t match any thing you showed). Please edit your question so we could help you further

Comment: Surely - I will update

Comment: If you could please explain how `final` was calculated for `id=aa` and `date=Q222`, neither 'final' = 'finalppm' - 't' + 'ex' nor  'final'- 'ppm' - 't' + 'ex' seems to produce 100 when the original value was 150.

Comment: (‘final’) 110 - ‘ppm’ - ‘t’+ ‘ex’     Essentially, 110-10

Comment: Once the first calculation is complete, per ‘id’ type, it shifts to use the ‘final’ column value as a baseline - which is 110

Comment: Hi @Lynn. Can you explain me the 560 on `bb` group. I found 550: `final(510) - ppm(10) - t(0) + ex(50)`

Comment: Hi @Corralien I believe you are correct - let me check really quickly please

Comment: Yes that’s correct it is 550- I have to update the other output - thank you

Comment: Can you give me the formula to compute `final_cnt` to be sure please? It uses `pos_diff` instead of `ppm`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic follows your previous questions:

```
# Compute constant part for each row
df['final'] = - df['ppm'] - df['t'] + df['ex']

# Update first final value of each group
df['final'].update(
    df.drop_duplicates(['id'])
      .apply(lambda x: x['finalppm'] - x['t'] + x['ex'], axis=1)
)

# Cumulative sum
df['final'] = df.groupby('id')['final'].cumsum()
```

Same logic for `final_cnt`:

```
df['final_cnt'] = - df['pos_diff'] - df['t_cnt'] + df['ex_cnt']

df['final_cnt'].update(
    df.drop_duplicates(['id'])
      .apply(lambda x: x['finalpos'] - x['t_cnt'] + x['ex_cnt'], axis=1)
)

df['final_cnt'] = df.groupby('id')['final_cnt'].cumsum()
```

Output:

```
>>> df[['id', 'Date', 'final', 'final_cnt']]
   id  Date  final  final_cnt
0  aa  Q122    110          5
1  aa  Q222    100          4
2  bb  Q122    510          7
3  bb  Q222    550          8
4  bb  Q322    500          0
5  bb  Q422    430         -5
```

Comment: ok thank you! I will try this out- was a bit confused since I added a new metric. Will follow same logic for final_cnt. Thank you for your knowledge and help

Comment: @Lynn, I updated my answer. Can you check, please?